# How to fix rhandsontable CSS in dark mode?

Tags: css, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

Currently working on an RShiny app that has a dark mode toggle. Works as expected except for the rhandsontable tables - their font color and background does not update with the rest of the app.

Here is the current logic for switching between modes:

```
observe(session$setCurrentTheme( # change dark-light mode
        if(isTRUE(input$mode)) { bs_theme(bootswatch = "darkly") }
        else { bs_theme(bootswatch = "default") }
      ))
```

I've tried including a call to bs_add_variables() to access CSS classes, but that hasn't worked either:

```
observe(session$setCurrentTheme( # change dark-light mode
        if(isTRUE(input$mode)) { bs_add_variables(bs_theme(bootswatch='darkly'), '.handsontable:color'='#992323', '.handsontable:bg-color'='#992323') }
        else { bs_theme(bootswatch = "default") }
      ))
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to address this? Thanks!

Reproducible Example

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

data <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=11:20,z=21:30,a=1:10*1000000,b=11:20*1000000,c=21:30*1000000)

if (interactive()) {
  shinyApp(
    ui = navbarPage(
      title = 'app', theme = bs_theme(version=5, bootswatch="default"), position = 'static-top', fluid = TRUE,
      
      tabPanel(
        'Demo',
        fluidRow(
          materialSwitch(
            inputId = "mode",
            label = icon("moon"),
            right=TRUE,
            status = "success"
          ),
          style='position: right; padding: 5px;'
        ),
        rHandsontableOutput('table')
      )
    ),
    
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      observe(session$setCurrentTheme(
        if(isTRUE(input$mode)) { bs_theme(bootswatch = "darkly") }
        else { bs_theme(bootswatch = "default") }
      ))
      output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data, stretchH='all')
      })
    }
  )
}
```

See above for reproducible example